# Suitable type to Store Linq result in order to be able to query it later

Tags: c#, linq, generics, linq-to-sql, types

I'm using linq to sql in my project. In **Form1** I query a table like:

```
var dc = new Data.MyDataContext();
var query = from c in dc.Customers select c;  
program.MainForm.query = query;
```

Or in **Form2** I query a table like:

```
var dc = new Data.MyDataContext();
var query = from b in dc.Banks select b;  
program.MainForm.query = query;
```

And I want to do something like the following later in **MainForm**:

```
this.DataGridView1.DataSource = this.query.Where(item=>item.ID < 10);
```

I don't know how to store the object. I tried storing it as an IQueryable but I was not able to query it because it is an Interface.

I want to store results from different tables in query, what is the simple way to do so? I think Generics can help but I don't know how.

Comment: You are mixing UI and data access. What benefit that will give you?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy we are trying to write a Custom Control which can handle any table result and we want to do operations in the Custom Control , for example we would like to search data inside the class. We load the data once and may perform inside search many times without fetching data again. And this Control must be used in different projects. That's why I want it to be able to handle data from different sources.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy imagine I was using DataTables, then I could store results from different tables with different column types and counts. That solution works in my situation, but I want to use LINQ because it is faster and easier to use and provides neater code which is easier to maintenance and develop.

Comment: You still can move all queries to another component and make it return only data which will be displayed on your control

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I want the Control to act like a base control. Exactly like how DataGridView works. It says give me the source, I'll handle the rest. I want my control to accept not different DataSources (like DataTable, List<T> and etc.), only accepting every LINQ result is sufficient. By every LINQ result I mean result from different tables, so I can not declare a specefic type. That is why I want it to be something like generic.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to hold on to the query you'll need a field of type `IQueryable<T>` with T being the type of object queried.

If you want to hold on to the result of the query (e.g. so you can search inside it in RAM without fetching the data again), you'll need some materialized data structure like `IList<T>`.

Both options are problematic because they require type arguments, and UserControls can't be generic. I guess you could work with `IQueryable<object>` and `IList<object>` but then you won't be able to do much with the resulting objects since the control will know nothing about their type.

As an aside, as @SergeyBerezovskiy noted, it's also probably not a great idea to mix data access and presentation logic like this.

Comment: It certainly isn't a good idea, the problem is that my customer wants this code. He wants it to be a magic box that can handle any type. If I use IQueryable<T> then can I use Reflection to make inside searches?

Comment: If you want to search inside the results using reflection, it sounds like you want to hold the results of the query (the actual objects) and do further manipulation on them (e.g. invoke property getters by reflection). For this you don't need `IQueryable` but an `IList`. `IQueryable` is only needed if you want to change the query before it is executed on the database (e.g. if the user control might add a new `Where` clause to the query).

Comment: @MahdiTahsildari: define "handle", please. What *exactly* are you going to do with query results?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the speed is very crucial for my customer. And AFAIK converting the result of a query to List takes a portion of time which is important, but if the conversion is the only way to do so I should accept a little loss of speed.

Comment: @Dennis I want to search inside them (based on different fields with different types and different methods - let's say for int we want a Range search and for string we want a Contain search), re-order them, filter them and such things